# Winforms DbContext Per Form

Tags: c#, winforms, repository-pattern, castle-windsor, unit-of-work

I am working on a WindowsForms application. I am using Repository, UoW, DI and EntityFramework. The best practice in such applications is to use a DbContext per windows form.

My problem is that when i resolve a form IoC, the form is injected with my business services. This should by default create a new DbContext instance, which is fine. When i open a sub-form from the same form, even though there are new business services injected into this sub-form, the same DbContext instance is used.

Even if i open a new form, the same DbContext instance is used, unless i release the resolved form.

Shouldn't be the case that whenever i resolve an component, and that component has several dependencies, then new instances from all will be created, especially since i am using Transient life style.

Below is short implementation of the code i use. I have included the important parts.

UnitOfWork:

```
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private DbContextBase context = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructer
    /// </summary>
    public UnitOfWork(DbContextBase context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets current context.
    /// </summary>
    public DbContextBase UoWContext
    {
        get { return context; }
    }
}
```

UnitOfWorkManager:

```
    public class UnitOfWorkManager
{
    private static IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork { set; get; }

    private UnitOfWorkManager()
    {
    }

    public static IUnitOfWork Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_unitOfWork != null)
                return _unitOfWork;
            else
            {
                _unitOfWork = Create();
                return _unitOfWork;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            _unitOfWork = value;
        }
    }

    private static IUnitOfWork Create()
    {
        return IoCManager.IoC.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
    public class Repository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : class
{
    public Repository()
    {
    }

    private DbContextBase Context
    {
        get
        {
            return UnitOfWorkManager.Current.UoWContext;
        }
    }

    private DbSet<TEntity> DbSet
    {
        get
        {
            return Context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
    }
}
```

Business Service:

```
{
public class BusinessService<TEntity, TKey> : IBusinessService<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : IEntity
{
    protected IRepository<TEntity, TKey> _repository;

    public BusinessService(IRepository<TEntity, TKey> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

DI Registration using Castle-Windsor:

```
IoCManager.IoC.Register<DbContextBase, PMDbContext>(IoCLifeStyle.Transient);
IoCManager.IoC.Register<IEFUnitOfWork, EFUnitOfWork>(IoCLifeStyle.Transient);
IoCManager.IoC.Register<IRepository>(typeof(IRepository).Assembly, IoCLifeStyle.Transient);
IoCManager.IoC.Register<BusinessServiceInterceptor>(IoCLifeStyle.Singelton);
IoCManager.IoC.Register<IBusinessService, BusinessServiceInterceptor>(typeof(IBusinessService).Assembly, IoCLifeStyle.Transient, typeof(BusinessServiceInterceptor));
//Forms
IoCManager.IoC.Register<frm_Main>(PM.Common.Enums.IoCLifeStyle.Transient);
IoCManager.IoC.Register<frm_Calander>(PM.Common.Enums.IoCLifeStyle.Transient);
IoCManager.IoC.Register<frm_Calanders>(PM.Common.Enums.IoCLifeStyle.Transient);
```

Comment: `UnitOfWorkManager.Current` makes sure that only single instance of `UnitOfWork` is created. That's why you have only single instance of DBContext.

Comment: Your right, but if i don't do this, then for each repository call, a new DbContext instance will be created, and this will break everything.

Comment: Why you want to create different DBContext for every form? You want to create new context for every form but don't want to create new repository for every new form?

Comment: It is a best practice to create a DbContext for every form http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2010/02/07/entity-framework-context-lifetime-best-practices/. Since i am using UoW, if i had more than one context i.e. one for each repo, then UoW won't work, since my implementation uses a manager that have a single UoW that contains a single DbConext.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your design little bit:

```
public class Repository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public Repository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    private DbContextBase Context
    {
        get
        {
            return _unitOfWork.UoWContext;
        }
    }

    private DbSet<TEntity> DbSet
    {
        get
        {
            return Context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
    }
}
```

Then whenever a new form is requested

- new service is injected
- which gets a new repository
- which gets a new
  unitOfWork
- which gets a new dbContext

Each call to the service within the same form will result in call to the same underlying -service -> repository -> unitOfWork -> context.

In case you have more services within the form which should share the same instance of uow:

```
Container.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWork>()
    .ImplementedBy<UnitOfWork>()
    .LifestyleBoundToNearest<frmBase>());
```

(https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md)

Then uow and its context would be scoped only to the nearest form.